# How to tell can I tell if my iPhone 5c is 3G or 4G?

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, 4g

I ordered an iPhone 5c for 4G usage. However, the phone I received displays a 3G on the top left of my screen.

Does 3G on the top left mean I'm using 3G?

Does this convert to 4G through proper configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see a 3G at the top left it means that you are in an area which does not have 4G support.

When you are in an area with 4G (or, on Verizon, LTE) you will see that in the top-left corner instead.

Comment: Sounds logical, however my current Android phone which is also on Verizon registers 4G. So two phones sitting side by side, my new Apple 5c reads 3G while my 3yr old Android registers 4G.

Comment: Could be that your Android is calling 4G that which isn’t considered 4G. Weird thing is that it’s happened to iOS too so I’m not sure why it wouldn’t show up there: http://www.tuaw.com/2012/03/14/faux-g-ios-5-1s-4g-indicator-is-the-tip-of-a-standards-icebe/

Answer (score 0):

iPhone 5c or 5s definitely support 4G or LTE and it clearly displays the 4G symbol. If it does not, it means your mobile service provider is not providing the 4G service or even if it does, maybe in some geographical areas the 4G service is not available.

Answer (score -1):

Only some 5c models support LTE, and they are only provided in certain countries..

See this list of model numbers..
http://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/

Comment: Every iPhone since the iPhone 5 supports LTE.